# Popular code for removing url field in comment form doesn't work anymore

Tags: wordpress

I've been using [this code](http://crunchify.com/how-to-remove-url-website-field-from-wordpress-comment-form/) (copy below) to remove url field from comment form in WordPress. It doesn't seem to work anymore. Why?

```
function crunchify_disable_comment_url($fields) { 
    unset($fields['url']);
    return $fields;
}
add_filter('comment_form_default_fields','crunchify_disable_comment_url');
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code worked for me:

```
add_filter( 'comment_form_defaults', 'remove_url' );
function remove_url( $fields ) {

if ( isset( $fields['fields']['url'] ) )
unset( $fields['fields']['url'] );

return $fields;
}
```